# Ionic 2-call number not working

Tags: ionic2

I wan't write app can call by number user input.

But i use http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/callnumber/ it not working.

it my code ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {CallNumber} from 'ionic-native';
import { Platform, ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';
// import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
declare var window;
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public actionsheetCtrl: ActionSheetController
  ) { }
  strShowInHtml = "";
  callIT(){
      // window.location = '12345';
      CallNumber.callNumber("12345", true)
  .then(() =>{
        console.log('Launched dialer!');
        this.strShowInHtml="ok";
  })
  .catch(() => {
        console.log('Error launching dialer');
        this.strShowInHtml="error";
  });
    }
}
```

and my code html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Action Sheets</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="action-sheets-basic-page">
  <button md-button (click)="callIT()">callIT</button>
</ion-content>
```

I know I can use

```
<a ion-button href="tel:+0839504890">Call me 1 </a>
```

but i don't want to use it, beaucase it will go to view Call Phone.
I want to click button and my app Ionic 2 will call number user input.

Answer (score 7):

In your Component class please write as below

```
callIT(mobNumber:string)      
{
       window.open("tel:" + mobNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're import isn't complete.  The documentation states to install the call-number plugin:

```
$ ionic plugin add --save call-number
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/call-number
```

And then reference the plugin:

```
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this way the other day. and worked :) I hope it works for you

```
  import {CallNumber} from '@ionic-native/call-number';

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
  NavParams,public call:CallNumber){}

     async callNumber():Promise<any>{
  try{
   await this.call.callNumber("+XXXXXXXXX",true);
  }

   catch(e){
    console.log(e);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this to solve the issue:

1. cordova plugin add https://github.com/Rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin.git
2. npm install --save @ionic-native/call-number

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ion-fab left bottom>
        <a href="tel:number" class="button" ion-fab color="light">
            <ion-icon name="keypad"></ion-icon>
        </a>
    </ion-fab>
```

Use this cordova plugin

```
mx.ferreyra.callnumber 0.0.2 "Cordova Call Number Plugin"
```